# how to replace single quotes with double qoute in jq

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have some thing like this.."Skin','Hair"...
i want result like this  ['Skin', 'Hair'];

I tried this

```
type: 'GET',
    url: '/HOME/Getselecteddata',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id: 8 },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;

        var endString = data.replace(/"/g, "'");
        var selectedCodeWBs = [data]
        $(".tokenizationSelect2").val(selectedCodeWBs).trigger('change');
```

Not working. please someone help me

my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Getselecteddata(int id)
        {
            var data = db.Segments.Where(x => x.Id == 7003).Select(x => x.Segname).SingleOrDefault();
            List<string> segmentdata = new List<String>(data.Split(','));
            string s2 = String.Join("','", segmentdata);



            return Json(s2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Use vanilla javascript instead.

Comment: Need some more information. Are you trying to do this once, or trying to set up a service that will accompish this with some input?

Comment: @SunnyPatel I just need to set the values selected in my select2 list box using this data

Comment: can you improve this input example `"Skin','Hair"`, did you mean `"'Skin','Hair'"`

Comment: My input was  "Skin','Hair"

Comment: I know it was, I told you in my comment, what I meant was that is a little bit confusing having those single quotes in the middle kinda floating there, but hey, it's your input sample, if you say it's correct, then it is. just for clarity now, could you provide us with a sample which contains more than 2 elements. also remember you can use `@` to notify a user when you are replying on his/her comment (like this `@J.M. Echevarría` at the beginning of the comment), that is of course if you were indeed replying to mine, otherwise it is not necessary

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría I have updated my Question with the controller code.I will have the element like this 1,"Skin','Fever".  2, "Skin','Fever,'Hair"..Hope its clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can much better do this:

```
return Json(segmentdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Using `segmentdata` directly will work 100% better than creating a messy string variable that contains unbalanced quotes.

MVC `Json()` is perfectly capable of working with a `List`, it will output it as JSON array notation. Then in your javascript the received value in `data` will already be a Javascript array that won't need further manipulating.